# Consuming TFS Web Hooks (Post via HTTP)

Tags: wcf, tfs

Is there a specific request format that the webhooks have? I am using the Pull Request Updated event, and I am trying to deserialize into a class, but I do not know what fields I will need. Is there a class or example of the request content details for the different events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a generic template for the HTTP post request/response from TFS.

The TFS HTTP post JSON request/response format is based on the specific action.

For example, for the web hooks whenever a work item is updated.If  I update a description field, I am getting one format and if I add a child work item, I am getting another format.

However for the specific event, you can check the response format, then get the useful information which you needed.

Please refer to [Send JSON representation to a service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=vsts#send-json-representation-to-a-service) for more information.
And at the end of the [Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=vsts#q--a) part there is a sample JSON.